# Detect and Highlight Font of text in TextBox in Font Dialog - C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a textBox with some default text with some predefined font. And i have a ContextStrip menu to change the font of the text in textBox.

When the font dialog pops, it doesn't highlight the font of the text.. but shows default font of size 8.

```
    private void fontToolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TextBoxTitle.Font = fd.Font;
        }
    }
```

How to highlight the font of text in the font dialog???

Comment: Did you try `texBoxYouWantFontFrom.Font`?

Comment: i think you misunderstood my question. The default font of the textbox is not highlighted in the font dialog. Rather, it always highlights the font size of 8

Comment: You say `When the font dialog pops, it doesn't detect the font of the text`, that's because you have to "detect" it, it doesn't do so on its own

Comment: Yup! that solved the issue

Comment: Thats good to hear ^^